# LiveData in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I need help on LiveData and ViewModel in Xamarin Android. I'm little bit new in Xamarin Android and I want to know how to use LiveData. I'm actual Android Developer and quite familiar how to use inside native Android. But here in Xamarin Android I tried it to use but i'm stuck little bit with IObserver Interface. In Android we generally use anonymous interface for Observer but in c# we can't do this. My question is how i deal with multiple livedata comes from ViewModel. How i can distinguish between different LiveData fields  from ViewModel. Following is my code you can see that only `OnChanged()` receive updates from ViewModel.

```
  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, IObserver
    {
        private MainViewModel ViewModel;
        private TextInputLayout artleNo;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_inventory_info);
           ViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this)
                               .Get(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainViewModel))) as MainViewModel;

          ViewModel.loadArticle().Observe(this,this); // That's fine for one LiveData What should i do 
         with Multiple livedata comes from ViewModel;

           ViewModel.IsLoading.Observe(this,this);
       }
   public void OnChanged(Java.Lang.Object p0)
    {
      //problem here how i can distinguish between different LiveData values?
     }
}
```

Regards,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options here.

1. In your `OnChanged()` method, you can check the type of the object and deduce the `LiveData` source. Unless, of course, they both have the same type: If that is the case, then you may be able to add an identifying attribute to the class that you are using.
2. As you can't use anonymous interfaces, you could explicitly define 2 classes that observe the `LiveData`, e.g.

```
    internal class LoadArticleObserver: Java.Lang.Object, IObserver
    {
        public void OnChanged (Java.Lang.Object o)
        {
        }
    }
    internal class IsLoadingObserver: Java.Lang.Object, IObserver
    {
        public void OnChanged (Java.Lang.Object o)
        {
        }
    }
```

And use them like this:

```
    ViewModel.loadArticle().Observe(this,new LoadArticleObserver());            
    ViewModel.IsLoading.Observe(this,new IsLoadingObserver());
```

It's more verbose than the Java code, but it keeps everything simple.